# Include YouTube video title in OneBox

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

Could we get the YouTube video title added to OneBox in chat?  This could either be on a line underneath the video preview, or a tooltip on the image similar to the way we get XKCD tooltips.

It's impossible to tell just from the onebox what the video is about, which is a shame, since all other oneboxing by definition are very easy to understand without having to click any links.

Comment: Yes, please....

Comment: And pull view counts like/dislike too?

Comment: @BarryCarlyon: No, just the title, like on any other oneboxed link.

Comment: @SecondRikudo the title is not fetched for xkcd... so it's not like "any other"

Comment: @Vogel612: Picky picky, anything other than xkcd than.